# Get color from wpColorPicker (Iris) after mouseup, keyup or done

Tags: javascript, svg, color-picker

I want to change fill color of SVG shape after user finish dragging on ColorPicker (wpColorPicker or IrisColorPicker) because there're dozen of SVG Shapes and every shape has a lot of circles, paths etc...

So i tried to find an event like [done, or something like that] in [AutomatticIris](https://github.com/Automattic/Iris/blob/master/src/iris.js) but i failed only [change] is available [Iris docs](http://automattic.github.io/Iris/) but because i get SVG shape from server using AJAX it's impossible to do this job in change event.

Comment: If such a change event is not available a common solution for these kind of problems is to clear and start a timer (by setTimeout) each time the change event occurs. So the timer only fires if the change event will not be fired for a certain time (the interval you set by setTimeout).

Comment: I'm trying to avoid this method so asked here perhaps there's someone know a solution

Comment: How o add SetTimeOut to Change function

$('..color-picker').wpColorPicker({
        change: function (event, ui) { }
);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common solution for these kind of problems is to clear and start a timer (by setTimeout) each time the change event occurs. So the timer only fires if the change event will not be fired for a certain time (the interval you set by setTimeout).

Here is a snippet that changes the color of the headline 1 second (1000 milliseconds) after the last change in the color picker:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    console.log('ready');
    var color = null;
    var timer = null;
    var changed = function(){
        console.log("Changed");
        $("#headlinethatchanges").css( 'color', color);
    };
    $('#color-picker').iris({
        width: 400,
        hide: false,
        change: function(event, ui) {
            if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = setTimeout(changed, 1000);
            color = ui.color.toString();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://automattic.github.io/Iris/javascripts/iris.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://automattic.github.io/Iris/javascripts/prism.js"></script>

<h1 id="headlinethatchanges">Iris Test</h1>
<input type="text" id="color-picker" value="#bada55" />
```